# How to debug a selenium request spec which fails when run in Jenkins build (but passes when run manually as a spec)

Tags: firefox, selenium, jenkins, jruby, capybara

I have a request spec written in rspec, using capybara:

```
scenario "request for a page with js driver", :js => true do
  visit "/foo" # redacted here, in my spec it's a legitimate URL
end
```

In my spec_helper.rb I have:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
require 'spec/spec_test_helper.rb'
require 'headless'

headless = Headless.new
headless.start

at_exit do
  headless.destroy
end
```

When I run this spec manually on a CI server, as:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/feature/sample_spec.rb
```

the spec passes. The machine in question runs Debian, has Xvfb and iceweasel installed. All good.

But when this spec runs as part of a Jenkins build on this machine, via Ant which invokes rspec, the "visit" command triggers the following error:

```
    unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)

    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:79:in `connect_until_stable'
    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:37:in `launch'
    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/socket_lock.rb:20:in `locked'
    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:32:in `launch'
    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:20:in `initialize'
    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `for'
    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:13:in `browser'
    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:34:in `visit'
    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:183:in `visit'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2080:in `send'
    ./.bundle/jruby/1.8/gems/capybara-2.0.2/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `visit'
```

I'm already using the latest stable versions of capybara, headless, selenium-webdriver.
This is running on jruby-1.6.7.2 in 1.8 mode.

I also tried using the Xvfb plugin for Jenkins, but that made no difference (and shouldn't be needed since the headless gem should manage starting up Xvfb for me). My impression from the error message is that the problem is in connecting to Firefox.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to debug this problem. If I could reproduce the error when running the spec manually while logged into the CI server, I would simply add "binding.pry" into the spec and use the pry console to debug. Unfortunately, this error only occurs when the spec runs as part of a Jenkins build.

Advice for my particular situation would be helpful, but I'd also appreciate advice on in general how to go about debugging the "unable to obtain stable firefox connection" error. Has anyone run into this kind of problem and found a way to gather more clues as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem using Selenium with Java. The solution was to use the [TakesScreenshot](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/DriverExtensions/TakesScreenshot.html) functions of the WebDriver to take a screenshot if my test fails and save it anywhere in the Jenkins workspace. Then you can see what was the state of the application. I don't know if it would be also possible to do that with Ruby and Capybara?